# Dependencies problems installing VNC Server in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5

Tags: rhel, rpm, vnc, xterm, dependencies

I'm triying to install `VNC Server` in a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5. I have the `.rpm` of VNC Server, but it has a depedency with `xterm`, which I have the `.rpm` too. Trying to install `xterm` it shows an error of dependencies too, this is the message:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libXaw.so.7()(64bit) is needed by xterm-293-25.1.x86_64
    libXmu.so.6()(64bit) is needed by xterm-293-25.1.x86_64
    libXpm.so.4()(64bit) is needed by xterm-293-25.1.x86_64
```

These dependencies I'm not able to find them and I cannot use `yum` command.

Anyone can help me to find out where I can download the suitable version for my system and tell me how to install them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library "libXaw.so.7" is provided by package with name "libXaw-1.0.11-2.el6.i686".
Download and install this package and then try to install vnc package/rpm

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't use the `yum` command? Also, are you trying to install tigervnc-server? Either way, you can approach this by using either:

`rpm -q --whatprovides libXaw.so.7`
or `yum provides libXaw.so.7` to find out what packages provide this shared object.

You should look into creating a repository from the RHEL 6.5 server install disc [Create RHEL Repo](http://linuxsysconfig.com/2013/03/create-a-rhelcentos-local-yum-repo-from-the-os-disk/). This way, resolving dependencies will become much easier, especially when they are apart of the main distro. Once you have a repository, simply run `yum install tigervnc-server`

Comment: I cannot use `yum` command because of security. The machine where I'm currently working has not access to internet. `rpm -q --whatprovides libXaw.so.7` shows this: `no package provides libXaw.so.7`